# Trouble with PyTorchLSTM in Thinc

Tags: python, lstm

Running the following code:

```
from thinc.api import chain, PyTorchLSTM, Sigmoid, Embed, with_padded, with_array2d

vocab_size = len(vocab_to_int)+1 # +1 for the 0 padding + our word tokens
output_size = 1
embedding_dim = 400
hidden_dim = 256
n_layers = 2

model = chain(
    Embed(nV=vocab_size, nO=embedding_dim),
    with_padded(PyTorchLSTM(nI=embedding_dim,nO=hidden_dim, depth=n_layers)),
    with_array2d(Sigmoid(nI=hidden_dim, nO=output_size))
)

model.initialize(X=train_x[:5], Y=train_y[:5])
```

I get this error: `ValueError: Provided 'x' array should be 2-dimensional, but found 3 dimension(s).`

Here is `x[0], y[0]`

```
[    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 21025   308     6     3  1050   207     8  2138    32     1   171    57
    15    49    81  5785    44   382   110   140    15  5194    60   154
     9     1  4975  5852   475    71     5   260    12 21025   308    13
  1978     6    74  2395     5   613    73     6  5194     1 24103     5
  1983 10166     1  5786  1499    36    51    66   204   145    67  1199
  5194 19869     1 37442     4     1   221   883    31  2988    71     4
     1  5787    10   686     2    67  1499    54    10   216     1   383
     9    62     3  1406  3686   783     5  3483   180     1   382    10
  1212 13583    32   308     3   349   341  2913    10   143   127     5
  7690    30     4   129  5194  1406  2326     5 21025   308    10   528
    12   109  1448     4    60   543   102    12 21025   308     6   227
  4146    48     3  2211    12     8   215    23] 1
```

I am relatively new to building these models, but I think it has to do with the fact that the output of the Pytorch LSTM layer has two dimensions. In a typical torch LSTM you'd stack the output from the LSTM layer (I think), but I'm not sure how to do that here. I assumed `with_array2d` would help but it doesn't seem to.